# How did Ellie Sattler rescue Dr. Grant and the others?

Tags: jurassic-park-3

Towards the end of Jurassic Park III, Dr. Grant makes contact with Dr. Sattler<sup>1</sup>. Being the loyal friend she is, she sends help...

> ...in the form of a few platoons of Marines based off a pair of the Navy's LHAs.

Who does she know that let her coordinate this kind of response?

<sup>1</sup><sub>Formerly Sattler, anyway.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ellie's husband, Mark, works at the State Department as we find out right at the beginning of the film (so it's easy to miss). I think it's safe to assume that when she hears the dinosaurs and Dr. Grant's cries for help on the phone that she contacts him and explains the circumstances. He then probably gets the wheels in motion to send a rescue team to Dr. Grant.

> ELLIE (CONT'D): So, Mark's working at the State Department now.
>
> GRANT: Really? (To Mark) What do you do there?
>
> MARK: (with mock bravado) I could tell you about it, but then I'd have to kill you.

It's fairly safe to say that given this exchange he's fairly connected and can definitely get the message to the right people.

Source: 
http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Jurassic-Park-III.html  (Scene 5)

Comment: To be precise, though, Ellie didn't really hear them or the dinosaurs cry, they lost the connection before she reached the phone. However, this doesn't change the correctness of the answer, since she clearly deduced what was going on from her son's expressions anyway.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Now I can't say for certain this is how it transpires in the film as it's been a long time, but if that script is accurate after the phone is cut off and her son says it's the Dinosaur man, Ellie rings back and hears the Dinosaurs and Grant calling her name before it cuts out again. Scene 106A for reference.

Comment: Hmm, I would have to recheck that. Maybe I remember it wrong then. But anyway, it's a largely moot point since the answer is correct nevertheless.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Yeah, her boy does say it was "the dinosaur man" and then growls at her. It cuts right after the kid growls, so she never calls back on screen. Of course, satellite phones report their location more accurately than cellular phones, so figuring out where they were was not a big deal... If you have the pull to get the data on short notice, anyway. Apparently Ellie no-longer-Sattler does.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what Grant shouted over the phone shortly before he was submerged in the water, but to me it sounded like he said "Site B" which refers to the Isla Sorna island